# While sending post request using ajax it is showing error

Tags: ajax

I am using this code for sending ajax request but it is showing 400 Bad request error. anyone please tell me the error in this. i am totally stucked.

Thanks.

```
 function bulk_setup_post_type() 
    {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'customstyle', plugins_url( 'admin/css/custom.css' , __FILE__ ) );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'customjs', plugins_url( 'admin/js/custom.js' , __FILE__ ) );
        wp_localize_script('customjs', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
    }

    add_action('wp_register_scripts', 'bulk_setup_post_type');



     add_action('wp_ajax_extract_upload_data', 'extract_upload_data');
     add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_extract_upload_data', 'extract_upload_data');



function abc(file){
        if(file!='')
        {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url : ajax_object.ajax_url,
                type : 'POST',
                data : {
                    action : 'extract_upload_data',
                    path : file,
                },
                success : function( response ) {
                //console.log(response);

                    alert(response);


                }
            });
        }
        else{ alert('File ' + file + 'not found.');}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your URL contains no domain name

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your response.
When i am checking request url it is showing  http://192.168.16.21/mcm/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php , which is right, i think.